# Filtering multiple values within a column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet with multiple columns with thousands of rows and trying to filter about 60 values within a column.  Instead of checking each value from the filter, is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the values. You might be able to select them all with a text search (just start typing in the filter drop-down, or choose an option such as "Ends With") or try a value search (e.g. "Greater than"). Dates can be grouped, so you can select a month at a time, say. If this doesn't make sense you could post some sample values for a more specific explanation.

If the approach doesn't immediately cut the mustard for you, you might find that adding an extra column with a formula you can easily select on will make the job simpler. For example, consider adding a column called "select?" and add a formula that works out whether a row should be selected by adding a "Yes" or a "No", e.g. =IF(A2/4=int(A2/4),"Yes","No") selects all the multiples of four. Then all you have to do is filter for the rows containing "Yes" in the new column.

Comment: If you have to check the SAME 60 values every time in different Excel Books you could create a Book called CheckValues with one sheet and all the values you want to check in column 1, then add the formula into an extra column in the sheet you want to check eg `=VLOOKUP(D6,'[CheckValues.xlsx]Sheet1 (2)'!A2:A78,1,FALSE)` and fill down to the end. The mentioned formula would check if the value in D6 exist in your list and show it, if not you would have a `#N/A` which you could filter out then - thus seeing only the values from your list. The CheckValues would have to be sorted in ascending order.

Comment: Yes, that's an excellent suggestion Zina! ;-)